# React Navigation V2: Difference between navigation.push and navigation.navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to React Native and I'm currently studying the [React Native Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html). I was wondering:
What is the difference between `navigation.push()` and `navigation.navigate()`?

I tried finding it out by myself, but they seem to accomplish the exact same thing...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you check the documentation for [`push`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#push), there is an explanation of how different they are.

> The Push action adds a route on top of the stack and navigates forward
>   to it. This differs from navigate in that navigate will pop back to
>   earlier in the stack if a component is already mounted there. Push
>   will always add on top, so a component can be mounted multiple times.

We can take Instagram for example;

Consider navigating to a user's profile. Then you can check user's followers and then you can navigate to their profile's too.
If you do this same actions with only `navigate` action, when you click on an user's profile from the followers list screen will navigate to the previous profile but if you use `push` it will push a new screen to the stack and show the correct profile. This way you can `goBack` to the first screen.

Comment: Same question for you: Will navigate also pop all the instances on between? Lets say I have 3 instances: A, B and C. Will A -> navigate B -> navigate C -> navigate A result in a Stack of just A or will the stack still be A B C? With push it would be A B C A right? :)

Comment: *navigate will pop back to earlier in the stack* from this I understand it pops all instances on between. I guess you can try it with a simple [snack](https://snack.expo.io/)

Comment: Furthermore if that screen is not already present in the stack it will push a new screen to it

Answer (score 16):

According to the last blog post [here](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/):
for v1:

`navigate(routeName) and push(routeName) were very similar: every time you called navigate(routeName) it would push a new route to the stack.`

for v2:

`Now navigate(routeName) will first try to find an existing instance of the route and jump to that if it exists, otherwise it will push the route to the stack.`

navigate > go to instance of page if exist or push a new instance

push > push a new instance even if one exist already

Comment: Will navigate also pop all the instances on between?

Lets say I have 3 instances: A, B and C. Will A -> navigate B -> navigate C -> navigate A result in a Stack of just A or will the stack still be A B C? With push it would be A B C A right?

Answer (score 5):

I think I can answer the question.

We have three pages:home page1 page2.

"home" is the "initialRouteName",and "page1" and "page2" is child pages.

So when we start with home,and push page1 (or navigate page1),the page stack is:

(2). page1

(1). home

and I push three times page2,the stack is:

(5). page2

(4). page2

(3). page2

(2). page1

(1). home

Now I want to go home, I can

1 pop Four times, or pop(4) directly;

2 navigate page1, then pop one time;

3 popToTop one time;

when page stack has no page1,navigate works the same as push,push page to top of stack and show the page.

when page stack has page1,the function of navigate is to jump to the page1 which is closest to the top of the stack,and pop others pages above page1.

For example, the following page stack:

(7). page2

(6). page2

(5). page2

(4). page1

(3). page1

(2). page1

(1). home

If you wan to go back to home,you should navigate page1 firstly ,then pop three times.

Tt should be noted that when current page is page1 and you navigate to page1,nothing

happened.

Here are some of the tests code I wrote,you just copy to App.js.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View,Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
 
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{}}>
      <Button
        title="navigate to page1"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('page1',{"pageName":"page1"})}
      />
      <Button
        title="push to page1"
        onPress={() => navigation.push('page1',{"pageName":"page1"})}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
 
function Page({route, navigation }) {
 
  return (
    <View style={{}}>
    <Text>{`current page is ${route.name}`}</Text>
       <Button
        title="navigate to Page1"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('page1')}
      />
       <Button
        title="push Page1"
        onPress={() => navigation.push('page1')}
      />
        <Button
        title="navigation to Page2"
        onPress={() => navigation.push('page2')}
      />
       <Button
        title="push Page2"
        onPress={() => navigation.push('page2')}
      />
      <Button
        title="Go to HomeScreen"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
      />
        <Button
        title="pop"
        onPress={() => navigation.pop()}
      />
        <Button
        title="popToTop"
        onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
     <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="page1" component={Page} />
      <Stack.Screen name="page2" component={Page} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
 
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to make it short and simple.

`Navigation.navigate` checks if the screen is in the stack so it takes there(to the older state) but `Navigation.push` just takes you to the new screen without checking if the screen was visited before and if that is available in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this makes it easier to grasp.

We start from A, go to B, then to C, then to B.

If in the last step (from C to B) we use `router.push`, then if we do `router.back` we will get to C (because a "new" B has been added to the stack).

But if in the last step (from C to B) we use `router.navigate`, then if we do `router.back` we will get to A (because navigate brought us back to the existing B).