# React navigation unable to navigate to just pervious screen after navigating multiple screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Scenario:

1. Navigate: Screen 'StoreCategories' --> Screen 'QRScanner'
2. Back press while at Screen 'QRScanner' redirect to Screen 'StoreCategories' working perfectly
3. Navigate: Screen 'QRScanner' --> Screen 'Options' and
4. Navigate: Screen 'Options' --> Screen 'QRScanner' again
5. Click on back while at Screen 'QRScanner' redirect to Screen 'StoreCategories' again

Not redirecting to its previous Screen 'Options'.

Everything happens with default back functioning in react-navigation, I am not using any custom function for back functioning.

How can I resolve it and navigate to just previous from redirection happens rather than already cached screen in react-navigation(V2)?

```
const StackNavigator = defaultRoute =>
createStackNavigator(
{
  CustomerLogin: {
    screen: CustomerLogins
  },
  MerchantLogin: {
    screen: MerchantLogin
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile
  },
  OtpVerification: {
    screen: OtpVerification
  },
  StoreOffers: {
    screen: StoreOffers
  },
  StoreCategories: {
    screen: StoreCategories
  },
  QRScanner: {
    screen: QRScanner
  },
  MerchantHome: {
    screen: MerchantHome
  },
  CustomerHome: {
    screen: CustomerHome
  },
  ThankYou: {
    screen: ThankYou
  },
  Detail: {
    screen: Detail
  },
  Options: {
    screen: Options
  },
  PayOnline: {
    screen: PayOnline
  },
  PayCash: {
    screen: PayCash
  },
  PayTm: {
    screen: PayTm
  },
  Token: {
    screen: Token
  },
  AddDiscount: {
    screen: AddDiscount
  },
  CustomerHistory: {
    screen: CustomerHistory
  },
  Webview: {
    screen: Webview
  },
  Direction: {
    screen: Direction
  }
},
{
  initialRouteName: defaultRoute
}
);
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to navigate to another screen? Is it the navigate function?

Comment: @rabbit87 I am using this.props.navigation.navigate("Main")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the current React-Navigation's navigate function works is a bit different then how they work previously. Currently if you navigate to a screen that is already in the screen stack, the system would go back to that screen (removing the other screens between the current screen and that screen will be remove) instead of simply adding a new screen to the stack.

If you want to use the old system style, you can use **push** instead of **navigate**. This would simply add to the stack instead of going back to the last one (if exist in the stack).

So rather than use

```
const {navigate} = navigation;
navigate(nextScreen, params);
```

you use

```
const {push} = navigation;
push(nextScreen, params);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working perfectly after changing navigate to push https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090135/react-navigation-v2-difference-between-navigation-push-and-navigation-navigate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090135/react-navigation-v2-difference-between-navigation-push-and-navigation-navigate

Answer (score 1):

if You want to navigate to back screen, you can use this code:

`this.props.navigation.goBack()`

by navigate to `Main` it will redirect to initial route of `Main` and it seems to be A