# App exit on back click on android in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

on Android Mi Note 3, hardware back button is not fire the `handleBackPress` , when I will click on back the app exit.

I have do the following code but the `handleBackPress` is not called.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {
    this.goBack(); // works best when the goBack is async
    return true;
  }
```

**Navigation Code :**

```
const ModalSignUp = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Signup: { screen: Signup, key: 'Signup' },
    PartyList: { screen: PartyList, key: 'PartyList' },
    StatesList: { screen: StatesList, key: 'StatesList' },

  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Signup',
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode: 'card',
  }
);
```

**Navigate :**

```
this.props.navigation.push("StatesList")
```

**Expected :**

back click on hardware button, go to previous screen.

Comment: do you want to disable the hardware back button functionality ?

Comment: No. I don't want to disable. But go for previous screen when tap on hardware back.

Comment: Have you tested that in other phones? This happens only in Mi Note 3 or others too?

Comment: Using react-navigation  Inyou are not able to go back ?

Comment: Yes. I use react navigation. in older version it's. Working. In my oldest App it's fine.

Comment: @Vencovsky it's Happening in all devices

Comment: @VinilPrabhu yes. React navigation used.

Comment: What version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: @Vencovsky 2.18.+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Import**

```
import { BackHandler, DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native'
```

**2. constructor**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.backPressSubscriptions = new Set()
  }
```

**3. Add and Remove Listeners**

```
componentDidMount() {
    DeviceEventEmitter.removeAllListeners('hardwareBackPress')
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
        let invokeDefault = true
        const subscriptions = []

        this.backPressSubscriptions.forEach(sub => subscriptions.push(sub))

        for (let i = 0; i < subscriptions.reverse().length; i += 1) {
            if (subscriptions[i]()) {
                invokeDefault = false
                break
            }
        }

        if (invokeDefault) {
            BackHandler.exitApp()
        }
    })

    this.backPressSubscriptions.add(this.handleHardwareBack)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    DeviceEventEmitter.removeAllListeners('hardwareBackPress')
    this.backPressSubscriptions.clear()
}
```

**4. Handle back**

```
handleHardwareBack = () => {
    this.props.navigation.goBack(null)
    console.log(" ********** This is called ************ ");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that you need to do this if you use `.push()` in all of your views. I have an app that use `react-navigation` and it works as you want without doing this. You said it happens in all devices, but i think is something only on specific devices.

Answer (score 3):

Your error can be in the way you get the next view of `react-navigation`.

You need to use `.push` to create a new view on the stack and when you click the back button, the `.goBack()` will be triggered.

By default, back button will always make the navigation to go back on the stack, but if you have only one view in the stack (this happens when you only use `.navigate`) the app will exit.

Not sure how you are navigating through the views, but this can be a solution.

**Edit:** To solve this problem, when navigating through views, **use `navigation.push('viewname')` instead of `navigation.navigate('viewname')`**. You don't need any other method (like the one you put in the question).

Also check the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html) to understand the how navigating works or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090135/react-navigation-v2-difference-between-navigation-push-and-navigation-navigate)

Comment: In stacknavigation have four view and I will navigate at the end view. I have added all view back button also. In which goBack() function is implementation. So the design back is fine. But if click on hardware back app is exit.

Comment: but you use `.push` or `.navigate` ?

Comment: navigate is used

Comment: @KiritModi please check my anwser, if you want to go back on the back button, use `.push()` instead of `.navigate()`, this is why the app exit instead of going back to the previous view

Comment: please show what you changed, the places where you navigate through views

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190247/discussion-between-vencovsky-and-kirit-modi).

Comment: Thanks for help, finally got the solution. I will answer of it.

Comment: See my answer it's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `return false` instead of `return true`.

Comment: This does work on some occasion if you have handled the event well

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import {BackHandler} from 'react-native';

export default class Component extends Component {
     _didFocusSubscription;
     _willBlurSubscription;
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this._didFocusSubscription = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus',payload =>
            BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressAndroid)
         ); 
     }
  }
componentDidMount() {
        this._willBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', payload =>
            BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressAndroid)
        );
 }
componentWillUnmount() {
        this._didFocusSubscription && this._didFocusSubscription.remove();
        this._willBlurSubscription && this._willBlurSubscription.remove();
    }
onBackButtonPressAndroid = () => {
    //code when you press the back button
 };
```

Comment: Yes, I also do same from react-navigation code. but not working also.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try... this one works for me: in `componentWillUnmount`

```
BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {});
```

Also, make sure in each case you check in your `this.goBack();` it `return` something

```
goback = () => {
   if (condition2) 
     // handling
    return something;

  if (condition2)
   // handling
   return something;

  // default:
  return true;
};
```