# which one to use between navigation.navigate vs navigation.push under which conditions?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I know how navigation.navigate and navigation.push work in react-native.

But I was wondering which is best to use under which conditions?
I have been through their documentation [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started) but can't get it clearly.

Thank you!!!

Comment: you can get and idea of navigation methods using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61967910/1435722

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use navigate when you want to navigate between screens. When you are in a screen and you try to navigate to this screen again then nothing is happening because you are already there.

Using push you can add a new screen on the stack dynamically, it's useful when you want to pass unique data each time calling the same screen.

Have a look here for more details and an example
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating/

I hope it helps