# with a StackNavigator in react-navigation v5, is there easy way to skip screens going/popping back but allow them pushing forward?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I have a StackNavigator, and I have a screen for creating new content on my app. Once the content is created I push to the screen for the content. At this point I can still create new content from that screen, so it's possible to push a new create content screen. But if the user does a GO_BACK, or swipes i.e. POPs back, I want them to skip the previous create content screen.

I think it's fairly common behaviour where you want to selectively skip screens on the way back. I've looked at the docs to try and figure this out. The easiest looking fix was the [auth-flow.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow) That skips the screen going back, but it also stops you pushing the screen if you take it out of the navigator.

The current best approach I have is to use a [custom stack router](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-routers), and in getStateForAction remove the create content screen from the routes whenever the user is pushing away from it. The downside on this is that there's a janky animation on iOS pushes from the create content screen, as the create content screen is sliding out it's also sliding up (I guess because it's being removed).

Is there a recommended best way to do this?

Comment: You can use navigate when going back with a given screenid, this answer explains each function https://stackoverflow.com/a/61967910/1435722

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the best way to approach it

Answer (score 0):

On the previous create screen use navigation.replace("ScreenName", {params})