# React Native: print a message when a page is opened or closed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to print a message when a screen is opened or closed. I am using `useEffect` to show when the component mounts and when it unmounts. This is the code for `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
     console.log("Starting Home");
    return () => {
        console.log("Ending Home");
    };
},[])
```

And the navigation in `App.js`:

```
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="About" component={About} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Here, when I open the app, it automatically loads the Home screen. The app works properly with About page and prints messages when it is opened or closed. However, it prints the message for the home page only once when the app is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show a message everytime a screen is focused you should use useFocusEffect instead of useEffect.

useEffect runs only when mounted and the Home screen is mounted only once.

Replace is with.

```
 useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log("Starting Home");
      return () => {
          console.log("Starting Home");
      };
    }, [])
  );
```

You will have to import it.

```
import { NavigationContainer ,useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It worked. But I have a question. Does the screen stay opened when I navigate to another page? Shouldn't be closed completely?

Comment: It stays on the stack actually, i have given a details explanation in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61967910/1435722