# I have faced problem in Stack Navigator in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

Suppose I have 4 tab screens. The tab is created with a custom footer component with layout concept and all the navigational screens are listed in the stack navigator route section and used goBack() method to navigate the previous screen. now For a situation, my navigation route as follows started with
Home->Testimonial->offerings, then again from offerings->Testimonial->about here I stopped in this screen then pressed the back button with goBack() function. but this time goBack() routes me to
about->testimonial->offerings->home. Like the unique screens are listed in stack navigators routes, not the duplicate screens.

I want to know is it an issue? if yes, then how can I manage it?

Comment: instead of navigation.navigate, try navigation.push. This guide might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090135/react-navigation-v2-difference-between-navigation-push-and-navigation-navigate

Answer (score 0):

Use a unique `key` for your screen.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/

```
   navigation.navigate({
       name: 'offerings',
       key: 'offerings' + someUniqueId,
   })
```